# See as much of Europe as possible in a week

Tags: schengen, europe, germany, paris, amsterdam

I don't know if this is a typical question that admins immediately close, but I am going to ask anyway.

I am from India. I have an opportunity to visit **Frankfurt** on Schengen visa. After my work is finished, I will have another **week's time** until I leave to India from Frankfurt. I would like to see as much as possible of Europe in this limited time. I would like to visit **Paris, Amsterdam and Prague**, and then I have to come back to Frankfurt to board my return flight. I have never been to Europe before.

1. Is a week's time enough to visit these places ? I just want to have a daytime's sightseeing in each city. Nothing extensive.
2. What is the economical and comfortable travel option from Frankfurt to Paris?
3. .. from Paris to Amsterdam?
4. .. from Amsterdam to Prague?
5. .. from Prague to Frankfurt?
6. In the (very unlikely) event that I still get extra time, I would love to visit Rome as well, any chances?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You should split this into several questions. Moreover you should use the search function as you can be pretty sure most of these questions have already been covered on TSE.

Comment: Ok I will. Sorry for the long question. I will anyway appreciate if anyone can at least tell me if this trip is possible in a week's time.

Comment: I don't think the question is so broad or open-ended. It's almost exclusively about transportation with specific requirements because of the nature of the trip. +1 from me.

Comment: Sounds like too much for a week.  Of course there is a subjective element to this, but personally I wouldn't be able to enjoy such a rush.  Consider carefully what you are expecting to get from this trip and what you will compromise by trying to fit in too much.  Yes, *doable*, but IMO it only makes sense if you do it for the thrill of going to so many places in such a short time ...

Answer (score 5):

As Relaxed said, taking the train is probably a good idea.

If you don't mind which order you visit the cities in, there is a [sleeper train](http://www.citynightline.de/citynightline/view/en/) from Franfurt to Prague, it leaves at 00.54 so you could leave on the day that you finish work and arrive in Prague the morning after, advance tickets seem to be available at €49 in a seat or €60 in a bunk bed.

From Prague you could take the sleeper train back across Germany to either Amsterdam or Paris (departing 17.15 for Paris or 18.30 for either, both require a change and I think you might have to book the two parts separately).

Regular daytime trains are probably best for the other sections of the trip.

To save money on doing this, book it as soon as possible, to get the cheapest fares.

Comment: thanks @djr great. I will think about which way to take.

Answer (score 4):

It's very rushed as there are many things to see in these cities and transportation will cost you dearly relative to the time spent in each place but obviously I can also see why you would want to do that and I think it should be doable.

Because you have so little time, the obvious choice between Frankfurt and Paris or Paris and Amsterdam will be the train. It's not the most economical means of travel but certainly fast and comfortable and it will maximize your time in each city. Take an early morning train and you will even have time for sightseeing before lunch (you can take a nap in the train!).

From Amsterdam to Prague, you could fly or perhaps take a late afternoon train to Cologne and then [a night train to Prague](http://www.seat61.com/Czech.htm#.VPSr9rvLj-s). The train journey is not particularly fast or convenient but you save a night's accommodation and avoid wasting precious daytime hours on transportation.

Connections between Prague and Frankfurt are not particularly good so the train does not have any major advantage on this route and you will lose a day to return to Frankfurt in any case. Depending on your budget and preferences, plane, trains, buses or perhaps a night train again could all be reasonable options.

For Rome, flying is really the only option, it's too far out of the way to use trains or buses when time is of the essence. That also means dealing the hassle of going to the airport, security, etc. twice. You'll have to check if you can find cheap tickets for flights with a convenient time and decide accordingly but it will obviously be extremely tight.

Comment: Thanks so much. From your reply I am going to drop the plan to go to Rome, and maximize my time in the other places. I wish I could upvote you, but I don't have enough rep :|

Comment: Do you think a Eurail pass is a good idea?

Comment: @tomol No, not for this trip. You are not going to hop on and off trains, don't have time for regional trains or improvisation and two of the four legs start or end in France, one of the worse country to use an Eurail pass. Seat61.com has an extensive discussion of when [it does or does not make sense to get a railpass](http://www.seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm#.VPS1TrvLj-s).